# Differentiate between & conflicts in url in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Let's say I have a page URL of `https://example.com/?pid=123&456&product=shirt&color=blue&size=m`

```
const queryString = window.location.search;
queryString // ?pid=123&456&product=shirt&color=blue&size=m
```

When I want to parse the url into an object I want the following output

```
{
   pid: '123&456',
   product: 'shirt',
   color: 'blue',
   size: 'm'
}
```

Instead I am getting output as

```
{
   pid: '123',
   456: undefined,
   product: 'shirt',
   color: 'blue',
   size: 'm'
}
```

How can I solve this '&' conflict?

Comment: That query string is invalid: if `123&456` should be the value of `pid`, then the ampersand must be escaped to `%26`

Comment: Well `&` is used in query string to seperate the pairs of property and value the url has, so in your case you need to replace that `&` character with `%26` so when your query string gets decoded you receive `&` that's all. so your `123&456` should be `123%26456` when you send it like a url and after decoding you get your `123&456` value